# Compiler Overhead: How much overhead does an IF condition in objectiveC impose?

Tags: objective-c

Please refer to the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
     }

 //... some other code 
 if (imageLoadingQueue == nil) {
    imageLoadingQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [imageLoadingQueue setName:@"Image Loading Queue"];
}
//... some other code 

return cell;
}
```

Now as we know the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called every time we scroll but refer to the conditions: `if (cell == nil)` &  `if (imageLoadingQueue == nil)`. This condition is checked again & again always.

**So I wanted to know how much performance overhead this if condition costs ?**

*EDIT: How do we measure that ? Any tool ?*

Comment: Not much at all, but why does it matter? Your program would be incorrect—or at least much worse off—without it.

Comment: Beware of premature optimization. There is no reason to optimize if there is no performance problem.

Comment: Do not worry about if statements too much. They compile to just two machine statements, if at all. In your case a value from an address will be loaded plus a branch if not zero. That is virtually noting. Plus execution for each visible(!) cell ist not much at all. 9 or 11 times from start and then on scrolling.

Comment: You and all of us probalby spent more time on that already than it will ever cost even if you sell millions of copies. :)

Answer (score 4):

The `if` statement itself will be negligible. It's possible that the *condition* used within the `if` statement may be significant (as in `if (somethingThatTakesTenSeconds()) ...`) but not so in this case, simply checking pointers against the `nil` value.

In any case, it hardly matters. If you need to select whether or not something happens, you *have* to use a selection statement, be it `if`, `select`, or a ternary operation. So how onerous it is doesn't really enter into the equation.